# Remove element from array by value Swift Language

Tags: arrays, swift

Is there a way to remove elements from an `Array` by value? For example how would I remove `"remove me"` from this array?

```
var stuff: [String] = ["remove me", "dont remvoe me"]
```

Comment: So... this website https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html didn't help you in any way? I found it by typing "Swift array" into Google and it was the first page.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `find` like this:

```
var stuff: [String] = ["remove me", "dont remvoe me"]
if let idx = find(stuff, "remove me") {
    stuff.removeAtIndex(idx)
}
stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `filter` operation

```
let newstuff = stuff.filter { $0 != "remove me"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Logan's answer no longer works with Swift, use this instead:

```
var stuff: [String] = ["remove me", "dont remove me"]
if let idx = stuff.indexOf("remove me") {
            stuff.removeAtIndex(idx)
        }
```

Works for me :)

As per documentation, indexOf: "returns the first index where value appears in self or nil if value is not found."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all elements in place, as opposed to creating a new array obtained by filtering (as in @rakeshbs' answer), then you have to find the index of the elements to remove:

```
let elements = filter(enumerate(stuff)) { $0.element == "remove me" }
```

and next remove all of them using a foreach loop:

```
for element in elements {
    stuff.removeAtIndex(element.index)
}
```

This solution removes all elements matching the filter, so useful in case the array may contain duplicates. You can also use @Logan's solution if you are sure there are no duplicates.

Note that `enumerate` returns a sequence of `(index, element)` tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that should do it:

```
func removeOccurencesOf<T: Equatable>(element: T, inout inArray array: [T]) {
    for index in lazy(0..<array.count).reverse() {
        if array[index] == element {
            array.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}

var stuff = ["remove me", "don't remove me"]
removeOccurencesOf("remove me", inArray: &stuff)
println(stuff)
// prints "[don't remove me]"
```